# Using interface defined in JSDoc in Typescript

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to setup TypeScript on a JS codebase with `allowJs` and `checkJs`

[I have a JSDoc that uses an interface as a parameter type](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/771fe520957199b32a26205c14f4816002842bcb/src/core/core.plugins.js#L30):

```
 * @param {IPlugin[]|IPlugin} plugins plugin instance(s).
```

[In the same file](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/771fe520957199b32a26205c14f4816002842bcb/src/core/core.plugins.js#L173), I have the interface defined via JSDoc:

```
/**
 * Plugin extension hooks.
 * @interface IPlugin
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
```

[This looks like valid JSDoc to me](https://jsdoc.app/tags-interface.html). However, TypeScript is failing on it:

> src/core/core.plugins.js:243:13 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPlugin'.
>
> 243   * @param {IPlugin[]|IPlugin} plugins plugin instance(s).

Any ideas how I get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

`@interface` is not supported by Typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc

It is suggested to use `d.ts` files instead: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33207#issuecomment-527680208

Might also be able to hack it by using `@typedef`: https://github.com/AlCalzone/ioBroker.js-controller/blob/9fbbb890290b07af5d9dfb7ae90bf92f2d0be178/lib/tools.js#L1329